# How to add new user in keyclaok using postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to add a user in keyclaok server using postman but i am not able to create.

Postman request:

Method : POST
URL : http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/ctms/users

Header : Auth

Request JSON Type in Body:

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "attributes": {},
  "emailVerified": "",
  "firstName": "DDDDDD",
  "lastName": "WWWWWWW",
  "email": "wwww@aaa.com"
}
```

Getting Response 403 Forbidden

{
     "error": "unknown_error"
   }

I am making a custom lonin page with New User & Sign-up user option but i am not able to create new user If anyone please tell me how to add new user in keyclaok using postman

Comment: User should have manage-users client role to create new users

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a 403 Error because you are not passing the right bearer token.
Here is an example

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/users' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '{"username" : "bburke", 
  "enabled": "true"
```

You can get the admin token using the below command

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli'
```

In place of username and password you need to provide the admin username and password and your client_id

Comment: Hi Avinash, Thanks for update but I am passing the right bearer token but i am still getting 403 {
    "error": "unknown_error"
}
If you have any demo project in GitHub plz share me link.

Comment: Can you show my how you are generating the bearer token ?

Comment: For token i am using below api in postman then i am getting token from keyclaok.
Method POST: 
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ctms/protocol/openid-connect/token
header : x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id=demo-app
grant_type:password
username:admin
password:password

Comment: So the basic idea is only an admin user can create a new user.And if you try to use some other token , the server will send u 403 forbidden ..A bit confused here as the same thing worked for me..Can u try to see the access_token lifespan  for the admin_token ? By defualt its 60 sec..If you call the create user API after 60 sec of invoking the admin API you should get 403 only..

Comment: I am using admin user token but i am not able to create user, can you plz share me full api details. or if you have any blogs & git url then it's fine for me.thanks!

Comment: I made a mistake in telling you the API for admin   


```curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli'
```

Use this to generate the bearer token   

Updated in the comment as well